# ember-i18n did not find a default locale; falling back to "en"

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I am getting this warning for ember-i18n (ember-i18n: 5.0.0)

I have set in defaultLocale: 'en' (As mensioned in ember-i18n docs)  in environment.js but still its populationg warning.

//environment.js

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        modulePrefix: 'spotlight',
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/',
        locationType: 'auto',
        EmberENV: {
           FEATURES: {}
        }, 

        APP: {
           defaultLocale:'en',
        }
    };
    if (environment === 'development') {
        ENV.APP.RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION = true;
    }

    if (environment === 'test') {
       ENV.baseURL = '/';
       ENV.locationType = 'auto';
       ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
       ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;
       ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    }
    if (environment === 'production') {}

    ENV.i18n = { defaultLocale: 'en' };
    return ENV;
};
```

//package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
      "ember-i18n": "5.0.0"
  }
}
```

//app/initializer/i18n.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
    name: 'i18n',
    after: 'ember-i18n',
    initialize: function()
    {
        var application = arguments[1] || arguments[0];
        application.inject('controller', 'i18n', 'service:i18n');
        application.inject('route', 'i18n', 'service:i18n');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what you are doing is right. may be stop and start `ember s`. this is just warning and in your case you are also trying to set locale `en`

Comment: @kumkanillam thanks, after installation of ember-i18n , i have run build more than 1000 times.

Comment: Inside i18n.js initializer code, `import config from 'app-name/app/config/environment';` and inside initialize method include `console.log(" config locale ", config.i18n.defaultLocale);` and inform me console output. [this](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/blob/dd5157db58fa230267bade5fc6543a3be0959037/addon/services/i18n.js#L77) is where warning thrown

Comment: I have checked it. ENV default properties are there but ENV.i18n is undefined. Is there need to enable/disable anywhere to access ENV properties.

Comment: update your question with exact code you in `config/environment.js` with default code. so that we can pinpoint exact problem

Comment: @kumkanillam i have updated complete config/environment.js code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136464/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-dilip-kumar).

Comment: I was not able to identify the cause of this issue.may some one with ember-i18n experience will give solution

Comment: @kumkanillam is it possible to make i18n globally available.

Comment: What do you mean globally? You already injected i18n service in route and controller, if you wan to include it in component you can add `application.inject('component', 'i18n', 'service:i18n');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It was because of home.jsp (my project init file) static meta content.

It was always setting with static meta content (home.js meta content) instead of environment.js file.

```
<meta name="spotlight/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22spotlight%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22hash%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22i18n%22%3A%7B%22defaultLocale%22%3A%22en%22%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_RESOLVER%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_TRANSITIONS%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_BINDINGS%22%3Atrue%2C%22RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D">
```